# How to replace corrupted Ubuntu files so my installation works again?

Tags: system-installation

Due to USB problems Ubuntu's files have been irrecoverably corrupted. However I was using Session Manager for Chromium which has saved a multitude of browsing sessions that are very important for my business and it would be very tedious to start "from scratch".

I thought that installation replaces whatever is on disk with files that work together to make a working OS so maybe it can replace the corrupted files with working ones without replacing my Session Manager sessions and other important files.

Ive used Windows previously and Ive had this situation once. I booted from installation DVD and selected something like "Repair Windows"

If this isn't possible with Ubuntu then  at least tell Me how to backup and restore Session Manager's browsing sessions.

Comment: If this isn't possible with Ubuntu then please at least tell Me how to backup and restore Session Manager's browsing sessions

Answer (score 0):

Well you can put installation USB into your machine and start installation process.

In installation menu you can choose to repair your Ubuntu installation (to replace system files and not to touch your personal files.

I suppose that Chromium sessions are stored locally (in `/home/user`) so you won't lose it reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Ill use find command to find the session files if you please tell Me what should I look for using find command?

Comment: It turns out it was Ubuntu with LXDE whiuch is known as Lubuntu.Will this work with Lubuntu too (the version is 14.04)

Comment: According to `chromium.org` your sessions are in `~/.config/chromium/Default`

Comment: Yes, it will work with Lubuntu.

Comment: I meant how to restore Session Buddy sessions https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko

Comment: in that case you can try to find it in `~/.config/chromium/Default` as it should be there. But, that is out of my scope